# How to use a macro append macro argument to a list?

Tags: elisp-macros

I want use a macro to generate a package list.

```
(defvar xx-packages '())

(genpack evil)
(genpack all-the-icons-ivy-rich
   :recipe (:host github :repo "seagle0128/all-the-icons-ivy-rich"))
```

this macro `genpack` will append argument to `xx-packages`,then `xx-packages` value is

```
xx-packages '((evil)
              (all-the-icons-ivy-rich
                   :recipe (:host github :repo "seagle0128/all-the-icons-ivy-rich"))
```

How can i write this macro `genpack`, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```el
(defmacro genpack (&rest args)
  "Append ARGS to `xx-packages'."
  `(setq xx-packages (nconc xx-packages '(,args))))
```

Comment: it works well thanks..